# Modify control template slightly using Style

Tags: wpf, combobox, styles, controltemplate

I just need to add a thick border around the `ComboBox`. As you may already know, ComboBox's `BorderThickness` property is not of much use. So I'm trying to modify the `Template` using following style, but can't figure out what I need to write inside the `Border` tag to represent the ComoboBox itself:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
                <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2">
                    WHAT GOES HERE?
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I have tried `ContentPresenter` and `ContentControl` but honestly don't know much about their usage in this particular scenario.

Comment: Related question: [WPF - styling comboboxes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2461883/302677)

Comment: @Rachel:Correct. Wonder how I missed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to edit the complete controlTemplate. Here is a small example you can extend at will.
First of all a controlTemplate for the ToggleButton that opens the combobox:

```
 <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="15" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Border x:Name="Border"  Grid.ColumnSpan="2" BorderThickness="1" />
            <Path x:Name="Arrow" 
              Fill="Black" 
              SnapsToDevicePixels="True" 
              StrokeThickness="1" 
              VerticalAlignment="Center" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
              Grid.Column="1" 
              Data="M0,0 L0,3 L1,3 L1,4 L2,4 L2,5 L3,5 L3,6 L4,6 L4,5 L5,5 L5,4 L6,4 L6,3 L7,3 L7,0 L6,0 L6,1 L5,1 L5,2 L4,2 L4,3 L3,3 L3,2 L2,2 L2,1 L1,1 L1,0 L0,0 Z" />
        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray" TargetName="Border"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="DarkGray" TargetName="Border"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="DarkGray" TargetName="Border"/>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

And here is the style for the combobox that uses this template.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                    <Border CornerRadius="5" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Red">
                        <Grid>
                        <ToggleButton x:Name="ToggleButton" 
                                      Grid.Column="2"
                                      Focusable="false"
                                      ClickMode="Press"
                                      IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                      Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}"/>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
                                        IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                        Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}"
                                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
                                        ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"
                                        Margin="3,3,21,3"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                        </ContentPresenter>
                        <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox"
                               Style="{x:Null}"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                               VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                               Margin="3,3,21,3"
                               Focusable="True"
                               Background="Transparent"
                               Visibility="Hidden"
                               IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}" />
                        <Popup x:Name="Popup"
                             Placement="Bottom"
                             IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}"
                             AllowsTransparency="True"
                             Focusable="False"
                             PopupAnimation="Slide">
                            <Grid x:Name="DropDown"
                                  Background="WhiteSmoke"
                                  SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                                  MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}"
                                  MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">
                                    <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder"  BorderThickness="1" Margin="0 0 2 0" />
                                    <ScrollViewer SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                        <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
                                    </ScrollViewer>
                            </Grid>
                        </Popup>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Well yes, this is what it looks like, if the OP follows my link. ;o)

Comment: @Olimpiu:Thanks a bunch. Precisely what I needed. Though it is a bit more work than I expected.

Answer (score 2):

Well if I get you right, you want to put the original `ComboBox` in that `Border`, right? You can find an example template customization [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
So if you copy the important part (the `Grid`) in your `Border` it should look like the standard `ComboBox` with a thicker `Border`. Perhaps you will have to do some minor modifications, so that it looks perfect. Btw, *MS Blend* would be a great help here.

Comment: :Thanks a lot DHN. I guess you and Olimpiu suggested the same thing, but he went on providing the actual implementation. Anyway, I guess your answer was the first one to appear and deserves an upvote.

Comment: Well I don't like to post copy and paste solutions. But anyways, glad that we could help you. ;o)